# Image rotated to left when compressed with bitmap.compress

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

I'm compressing image and uploading it to server. If i upload it without compress image is ok but very large size. But if i compress it before uploading then i will get rotated image on server. Code is below for compressing:

```
File oldFile = new File(destPath);
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(oldFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: No it will not get rotated on the server. But on the client.

Comment: It is unclear where your bitmap comes from. You should upload a file. Not an image. What ever you mean with image. What ever you mean with uploading without compressing. Totally unclear. Cant you start your story st the begin?

Comment: @greenapps Image is coming from camera.Images are being save fine without compression Problem is that when i compress images these are being save by rotating left.

Comment: Normally the camera app does not give you an image but saves an image to file. So for me it is unclear where your image comes from. Please be clear. Second time i ask.

Comment: that is common sense file always save as file from camera and If you look in code. I'm using its path from cursor with that code: String destPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

Comment: If you refuse to give decent explanations  and complete code then how do you think someone can help?